# Phrase indicating recruiters should not offer services in response to a job opening

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

In Dutch, there's a specific phrase / idiom you can use when posting a job opening to indicate that it's not appreciated if recruitment agencies offer to find a candidate for you ("*Acquisitie naar aanleiding van deze vacature wordt niet op prijs gesteld.*"); i.e. you only want *direct* applications.

Is there a similar phrase or idiom for this in English? [The automated, literal translation](https://translate.google.nl/#nl/en/Acquisitie%20naar%20aanleiding%20van%20deze%20vacature%20wordt%20niet%20op%20prijs%20gesteld) doesn't seem quite right, nor can I think of- or find a phrase for this.

Comment: 'Only direct applicants need apply'? Just a suggestion, not a set phrase/idiom.

Comment: Sometimes you'll see "Principals only. No recruiters please."

Comment: @TimRomano I ended up using your suggestion. Care to write it up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the phrase suggested by @TimRomano in a comment (emphasis mine):

> Sometimes you'll see "**Principals only. No recruiters please.**" – Tim Romano Jul 7 '15 at 14:01

Answer (score 4):

The common wording in the UK is "No Agencies [please][!]". Options supplied there depending on how polite you want your requirement to appear.